# prisma2: How to filter by a non required field in prisma.user.findMany()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

This is my prisma datamodel:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id               Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email            String   @unique
  name             String
  password         String
  emailVerified    Boolean  @default(false)
  emailToken       String?
  emailTokenExpiry Float?
  createdAt        DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

here, `emailToken` is an optional field. but I want to filter by this field. 
something like this:

```
await prisma.user.findMany({where: {emailToken: emailToken}})
```

But, prisma allows only required fields to filter that. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to filter by optional fields.
for example, this snippet works for me.

```
const [user] = await prisma.user.findMany({
      where: {
        emailToken: args.emailToken,
        emailTokenExpiry: {
          gte: Date.now() - 3600000,
        },
      },
    });
```